# Most Cron Jobs show as missed

Tags: magento2, database, cron

I recently installed a new Magento 2.2.6 website on a VPS server. Everything seemed to install correctly. The issue I have now is the logs in the var folder are not being populated (update.cron.log, setup.cron.log, magento.cron.log) and the MySQL Database cron_schedule has almost all of the scheduled tasks marked as missed. These are the settings in Magento admin under store>configuration>advanced>system>cron:

Schedule:15
Schedule ahead:20
missed: 45
history 10
success lifetime: 60
failure Lifetime: 600
Use separate process: No

I had an old Magento 2.1 site on a shared host which I had to cancel due to lack of SSL Renewal. The Cron Jobs all worked properly the cron_schedule table populated with all success and the log files are populated. I can not figure out what is wrong. The file and folder permissions are correct as far as I know (var folder 777, var/log 777, all cron.log files 644) Please help this is driving me crazy.

Comment: Please check in cmd that is it available if yes then we can go further with that otherwise it might be permission issue.

Comment: select job_code from cron_schedule GROUP BY job_code;

Comment: I ran this command [grep "cronscript.php" /var/log/cron] and received access denied. I think maybe it is a permission issue. After talking to my host provider they say cron is running and set me a log for the 3 cron jobs. Is it possible that the jobs are running but due to permissions the cron_schedule table is not updated to reflect success and the logs are not being populated?

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned you have setup Magento in new VPS server.

so maybe you missed to set up cron in `crontab` please check `crontab -l` from root directory via ssh.

Did you see cron setup there? if not then please use `crontab -e` to setup cron in `crontab` and paste below code there.

```
#~ MAGENTO START
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v Ran jobs by schedule >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/update/cron.php >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/setup.cron.log
#~ MAGENTO END
```

for more details follow below link

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

I think you should install free magento2 extension to check your cron status if not installed where you can track your cron

https://www.wyomind.com/cron-scheduler-magento.html

Comment: I ran crontab -l and all 3 cron jobs are listed. As I commented in the previous commentor above I spoke to my host provider and they say the logs show the cron jobs are running. Could it be a permission issue preventing the system from updating the cron_schedule to success and the var/log files from being populated?